# Access denied BO prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

In main page BO, Catalog ->Products -> Edit ()->Combination->Product combinations generator and in Administration -> Permissions ->Edit access is denied.I attached print screen.[image] How resolve that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most likely, you logged in with non-administrator account. That is why you do not have these permissions/access. Try logging in with the account that you created when you installed Prestashop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find in ps_access tab AdminHome and edit this row.put 1 everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I've already been hit by this issue and the thing is that, even if you are logged in as admin, some permissions/tabs are not created during upgrades.

Try to create a tab for the feature you are trying to access and then the permission will be created correctly for the Super Admins.